# Groupby - Generate date time as sequence

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
session      slot_num
s1           1
s1           2
s1           3
s1           3
s1           4
s1           4
s2           1
s2           2
s2           2
s2           3
s2           4
s2           5
s2           5
s2           6
s3           1
s3           1
s3           2
s3           3
```

from the above I would like to create a column appt_time as shown below.

Expected output

```
session      slot_num     appt_time
s1           1            2020-01-06 09:00:00
s1           2            2020-01-06 09:20:00
s1           3            2020-01-06 09:40:00
s1           3            2020-01-06 09:40:00
s1           4            2020-01-06 10:00:00
s1           4            2020-01-06 10:00:00
s2           1            2020-01-06 08:20:00
s2           2            2020-01-06 08:40:00
s2           2            2020-01-06 08:40:00
s2           3            2020-01-06 09:00:00
s2           4            2020-01-06 09:20:00
s2           5            2020-01-06 09:40:00
s2           5            2020-01-06 09:40:00
s2           6            2020-01-06 10:00:00
s3           1            2020-01-09 13:00:00
s3           1            2020-01-09 13:00:00
s3           2            2020-01-09 13:20:00
s3           3            2020-01-09 13:40:00
```

Explanation:
for session = s1, appt_start time = 2020-01-06 09:00:00, then for each increase in slot_num for that session increment appt_time by 20 minutes.

for session = s2, appt_start time = 2020-01-06 08:20:00, then for each increase in slot_num for that session increment appt_time by 20 minutes.

for session = s3, appt_start time = 2020-01-09 13:00:00, then for each increase in slot_num for that session increment appt_time by 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary specified first datetimes for each `session`, here is used dictionary with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), conver to datetimes and then add timedeltas by 20 minutes by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with subtract `0` for added `0 Timedelta` for first group and multiple for `20 minute`s:

```
d = {'s1':'2020-01-06 09:00:00',
     's2':'2020-01-06 08:20:00',
     's3':'2020-01-09 13:00:00'}

df['appt_time'] =  (pd.to_datetime(df['session'].map(d)) + 
                    pd.to_timedelta(df['slot_num'].sub(1), unit='T').mul(20))
print (df)
   session  slot_num           appt_time
0       s1         1 2020-01-06 09:00:00
1       s1         2 2020-01-06 09:20:00
2       s1         3 2020-01-06 09:40:00
3       s1         3 2020-01-06 09:40:00
4       s1         4 2020-01-06 10:00:00
5       s1         4 2020-01-06 10:00:00
6       s2         1 2020-01-06 08:20:00
7       s2         2 2020-01-06 08:40:00
8       s2         2 2020-01-06 08:40:00
9       s2         3 2020-01-06 09:00:00
10      s2         4 2020-01-06 09:20:00
11      s2         5 2020-01-06 09:40:00
12      s2         5 2020-01-06 09:40:00
13      s2         6 2020-01-06 10:00:00
14      s3         1 2020-01-09 13:00:00
15      s3         1 2020-01-09 13:00:00
16      s3         2 2020-01-09 13:20:00
17      s3         3 2020-01-09 13:40:00
```